# Why does Russia hate the West?

Tags: russian-federation, western-world

Historically Russia seems to always oppose pro-western regimes. There is this something I can not fully grasp. Given how miserable life is in Russia, how repressive their people are, it is strange that they would fight western invasion such as Nazis or Napoleon or even attempts of democratization with such determination.

Again, I am not trying to make comparison of Nazi and McDonalds, and it was not my intention to invoke all those arguments about how bad fast food is for your health. My question is only about why Russia resists westernization. Nazi come to mind, because I recall they could find collaborators in many regions of Europe, in Baltic states and in Ukraine they were more successful and met less resistance. I attribute it to the specific dislike Russians, and not Ukrainians or Lithuanians, had against western anything.

Comment: It sounds like your question boils down to "My side, and the media I consume, think we're better than their side, why don't they just let us invade them?" - which either doesn't grasp the potential of people having a different opinion to you or the question is disingenuous.

Comment: @LioElbammalf absolutely you are correct. I don't have enough time to consume western media, so I am hoping to exploit some of the community knowledge and expertise

Comment: I am stunned with people imagining Nazi occupation on East was similar to "Allo, Allo" sitcom. Hitler considered Slavs subhumans. Germany did not offer westernization to Russia. It offered genocide of Poles, Russians etc.

Comment: Seriously as a German I'd urge you to first research and then delete the part where you mention the Nazis and democratization in the same sentence. The Nazi ideology considered the slavic people as an inferior race and aimed at expanding the German territory to the east, planning to exploit, deport and purge the native population. There's a reason the late stage and post-war Germany was very afraid of the Russians given the horrors they committed there.

Answer (score 5):

Frame challenge #2: McDonalds [was](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/mcdonalds-made-its-soviet-debut-30-years-ago-its-golden-arches-were-a-gateway-to-western-civilization/2020/01/31/8869b2e6-4296-11ea-99c7-1dfd4241a2fe_story.html) apparently welcomed in Russia and *they* [pulled out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonald%27s_in_Russia#Shutdown,_replacement_and_aftermath) (only their franchise, because that's how they operate) at pressure of Western media/consumers, rather than being "repelled" by the Russians. So comparing McDonalds with the Nazis is apples to oranges in so many ways...

And if you want to talk [Western] political values, Putin has [courted](https://carnegieendowment.org/2020/02/27/with-friends-like-these-kremlin-s-far-right-and-populist-connections-in-italy-and-austria-pub-81100) right-wing populists in Europe. Yeah, this is in part purely tactical--the Kremlin's response to what they see as Western/liberal-inspired color revolutions in their sphere of influence. But Putin has been (liberally) raging against liberal values [for a while](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-russia-putin-europe-values-idUSKCN1TS2UF/). If you really like historical arches, this isn't that far from how tsarist Russia approached Westernization: they approved of it to some extent (army modernization, some industrialization), but not so much on the political level--the 3rd Duma [of 1907-1912](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_Duma_(Russian_Empire)#Third_Duma) was a little more successful it terms length tenure that its two (rather quickly dismissed) predecessors, but still rather decorative, and more tolerated by the tsar because it was more conservative.

And if you believe [polls](https://globalaffairs.org/research/public-opinion-survey/do-russians-fear-west) taken in Russia after Feb '22, they seem to believe what they are being told by the officialdom, that NATO is a threat to Russia etc.

> [image]

Alas that poll doesn't cover much else in terms of attitudes, beside those towards NATO (at least the translation doesn't). But a year later (May 2023):

> Seven in 10 said NATO membership for Ukraine would be a threat to Russia (71%), and preventing Ukraine’s NATO membership is seen as a top benefit of the Russian military action in Ukraine.
>
> At the same time, seven in 10 Russians do not fear an imminent attack from NATO (53% unlikely, 20% absolutely improbable). [...]
>
> A plurality of Russians did not believe their country’s actions are responsible for Finland and Sweden’s applications to join NATO (49%).

Also "territorial gains" was listed as the main benefit of the "special military operation" by a plurality (29%), with "stopping NATO" by 15%.

There's a [2015 retrospective](https://carnegiemoscow.org/commentary/60457) of other polls which is a bit too long to quote much from, but these bits seemed interesting enough:

> [Around 1999,] 75% of Russians agreed with the statement that “the U.S. is taking advantage of Russia’s troubles to turn it into a second-class country,” and 60% were confident that the U.S. wanted Russia to break into several parts, but only 8-9% considered a military conflict between the U.S. and Russia to be a serious possibility. [...]
>
> In the mid-2000s, the U.S. and NATO rose to the top of the list of “Russia’s enemies” and the U.S. was listed among those states “most hostile towards Russia.” [...]
>
> In 2008, half the population believed the main cause of the war with Georgia was the U.S.’s desire to "extend its influence to Russia’s neighbors”; another 32% blamed Georgia, and only 5% considered Russia responsible. This demonstrates another common reaction to the collapse of the Soviet Union: an unwillingness to respect the agency of former Soviet republics and a refusal to acknowledge that some of them might choose to follow a Western model rather than a Russian one. This pattern can be observed in the situation with Georgia, with NATO accession, and mostly recently with Ukraine. [...]
>
> The annexation of Crimea, the inability of the West and the U.S. to do anything about it, and a sanctions war, gave a majority of Russians the sense for the first time since the collapse of the Soviet Union that their country was a superpower (70% of respondents feel this way [in 2015], compared to just 47% in 2011). This represents a certain retribution for their defeat in the Cold War, and compensation for Russia’s inability to catch up with the U.S. in living standards.  Participants of a special focus group used phrases such as “they're paying attention to us again,” “we bared our teeth,” and “they will have to reckon with us.”

Comment: McDonalds was outselling everybody else by a huge margin thanks to first mover advantage. In the foodcourt, they always had a line whereas other stalls had one customer or personnel resting waiting for customers. Now it still does to some extent, but now lining somebody else's pockets.

Comment: @alamar: FWTW, that WaPo piece said that KFC  was more popular by 2020 (and they seem to mean in Russia). And yeah, KFC also sold their franchise in Russia recently https://www.reuters.com/business/retail-consumer/russia-revives-fried-chicken-chain-rostics-after-kfc-owner-finalises-exit-2023-04-25/

Comment: Can't begin to imagine that. KFC has its uses but that's comparing Toyota with Fiat. McDonalds is *the* fast food in Russia.

Comment: Georgian war is the one which Georgia had poor judgement to start and then lose. I can only see ideological embedding where the article is talking about "unwillingness to respect the agency of former Soviet republics". It still seems to be the truth from 2023 that USA has persuaded and encouraged Georgia to attack South Ossetia, which was *a bad idea*.

Comment: "Inability to catch up with U. S. in living standards" is also another ideological quagmire, since even long-term democracies such as Canada or South Korea are arguably unable (or unwilling) to catch up with U. S. consumption standards. The stated target is unrealistic and represents a straw man argument.

Comment: @alamar: maybe, maybe not if one considers that Russia vies for superpower status.  I guess it depends what one considers should go along with that. Russia is seldom comparing itself with Canada on just about anything.

Comment: Russia is actually comparing itself with Canada quite often. Also, China is a superpower without hitting anything near US level of consumption per capita.

Answer (score 2):

Frame challenge:

> Given how miserable life is in Russia

is a popular misconception. A Russian peasant of the century XVIII often had a huge plot of land, by the Western European standards, and he owed a limited share of produce to his landlord, leading to quite high living standards.

True, if there was a famine of some sort, it was miserable, but on good years he and his family would enjoy quite lavish lifestyle. I would say that most of the Western social inventions made his life worse. More strict serfdom rules were a German influence. Getting peasants off the land to man factories for a tiny wage was an English one. Peasants getting involuntarily enlisted to the military was a French invention.

Russia likely had no choice but to modernize, but getting everybody in a concrete flat is hardly a positive lifestyle change. Life is getting more competitive, compensating you with trinkets.

So the question is, the assumption that a foreign occupation will make things better is baseless. Occupation will not turn Russia into France climate-wise (no vines, no cheeses) but will surely disrupt existing way of life, which kills people literally when the average winter temperature is -20C. And that happened quite often in the last century and a half.

Comment: **The discussion about the quality of life of 18th century serfs has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151987/discussion-on-answer-by-alamar-why-does-russia-hate-the-west); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.